# Folders are not moved in subfolder: something weird is going on with cygwin's version of find?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I don't understand if something weird is going on with cygwin's version of find.

In `Z:\ANIME E CARTONI\# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD\# 22` I have these folders

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

folder1 and folder2 have a size > 4mb so in theory they should be moved to the over40gb folder but this does not happen

```
#!/bin/bash
z="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22"
target="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22/over40gb/"
size="3M"
mkdir -p "$target"
find "$z" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +"$size" -exec mv "{}" "$target" \;
```

EDIT: this solution works

```
z=/cygdrive/C/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/
mkdir -p /cygdrive/C/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/over40gb/
for x in $(ls -1 --color=never -d ${z}*/); do
  y=$(du --max-depth=0 --block-size=1M $x | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $y -ge 4 ]; then
    mv ${x} /cygdrive/C/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/over40gb/
  fi
done
```

But it return me an error message

```
mv: cannot move '/cygdrive/C/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/over40gb/' to a subdirectory of itself, '/cygdrive/C/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test/over40gb/over40gb'
```

but when I try to use path with spaces like

```
z="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22"
mkdir -p "/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22/over40gb/"
for x in $(ls -1 --color=never -d ${z}*/); do
  y=$(du --max-depth=0 --block-size=1M $x | awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $y -ge 4 ]; then
    mv ${x} "/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22/over40gb/"
  fi
done
```

it return me this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4rEU.png

Comment: `${z}*` should be `"$z"*`.   Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find missing quotes, and other common shell programming errors.

Comment: I fix this but still doesn't move folder1. folder2 and folder3 in over40gb. It tell me for `first line Line 1:
z="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22"
^-- SC2148 (error): Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.` - What does it mean? I use this version of cygwin https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: Explore `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} mv {}` option. uses null as item separator to avoid problems with filenames.

Comment: make it simple and create a link for over40gb or for the parent folder then use the link in your script

Comment: @ufopilot sorry, I don't understand, for line `for x in $(ls -1 --color=never -d "${z}"*/); do` it tell me (warning): Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs. but I don't understand how to change it also if I look here [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2045)

Comment: The [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports includes links to full descriptions of all problems that it identifies.  For the shebang issue the link is [ShellCheck: SC2148 - Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2148).  Also see [Shebang (Unix) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Aside from the bug with the missing quote: [Don't parse the output from ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), in particular since it is completely unnecessary in your case, as you could have simpy written `"$z"/*` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-quote your variables expansions and filter out the directory `over40gb`. Also, using `ls` is no good.

```bash
z="/cygdrive/Z/ANIME E CARTONI/# DA SISTEMARE ED ESTRARRE _ DVD/# 22"

mkdir -p "$z/over40gb" || exit 1

for dir in "$z"/*/
do
    [ "$dir" = "$z/over40gb/" ] && continue

    size=$(du -sk "$dir" | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}')

    [ "$size" -ge 4096 ] && mv "$dir" "$z/over40gb/"
done
```

<sup>**note:** `NR == 1` might seem superfluous but it's a safeguard against the possible newline in a path</sup>

Comment: something is wrong: if I write `-ge 30000` it moves also folders of 5gb and not only folders from 30gb. What is the problem ?

Comment: I replaced the `du --max-depth 0 --block-size=1M` with the standard `du -sk` whose output is in kB; for a 30GB file the size check would be `-ge 30000000`

Comment: Ok, thank you. There is a thing that I don't understand: if I run this command on a network path for strange reason folders are not moved, but over40gb folder is created but this not happens if I use a local path. Please look [HERE](https://s8.gifyu.com/images/20220606_234240.gif) - do you have idea for what reason should be happens ? Maybe `du` is deprecated for network path ?

Comment: t seems like the loop didn't complete; how long does it take to run `time du -sk "$z/Getta Robot ..."`? Is `time find "$z/Getta Robot ..." -type f -printf '%s\n' | awk '{ s += $1 }; END { print s }'` faster?

Comment: no, both command for network path is like frozen when running this commands and cursor blinks in terminal while for local path I see immediately the time data (real, user, sys)

Comment: So the issue is related to the network... it seems like accessing SMB shares from Cygwin can be a pain, I don't know the reason though. If you just do a `find "$z/Getta Robot ..." -type d`, do you get an output in a reasonable time?

Comment: If I type `find "Gatchaman - La Battaglia Dei Pianeti (1972) 11xDVD9 ITA ENG" -type d` it show me immediately the name of folder. In the meantime I passed the problem to the Raidrive software support because it is practically the Google Drive disk mounted locally. Maybe they have some flaw in their program.